# Functionality Similar to SUMIFS with DAX?

Tags: powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

Sample workbook: http://1drv.ms/1VDgAjf

I've got a table similar to:

```
ActiveDate  CommenceDate    Amount
-------------------------------------------
20150115    20150201    10
20150115    20150201    2
20150223    20150301    3
20150223    20150202    5
```

I need to calculate the following:

```
Date    Amount
---------------------
25-Jan-15   0
30-Jan-15   0
04-Feb-15   12
09-Feb-15   12
14-Feb-15   12
19-Feb-15   12
24-Feb-15   17
01-Mar-15   20
06-Mar-15   20
11-Mar-15   20
```

So.. in Excel I've tested this with the following statement:

```
=SUMIFS(
    Table[amount]
    ,Table[commence] ,"<="&TEXT(<<DateRef>>, "yyyymmdd")
    ,Table[active] ,"<="&TEXT(<<DateRef>>, "yyyymmdd")
)
```

This works fine.. my question is, how do i replicate this in DAX?

Here is my best stab (assuming a date dimension, and it connected to "CommenceDate"):

```
TotalAmount :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table[Amount] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
        'Date'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
    )
)
```

My best idea (and i think it's a pretty crappy idea), is to add a new column that gives me the greater of ActiveDate, or CommenceDate and then use an in-active relationship to join to that, and make the relationship active ***just*** for this calculation?

```
=IF([@active]>[@commence], [active], [commence])
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your thought of creating an additional column is probably the best in this case. No matter what you do, you'll have to escape the active relationship between Transactions[commence] and DimDate[DateKey] to get this logic working correctly.

After doing that manipulation, you'll then have to filter on two columns ([active], [commence]) against the current date in context. This will be more cumbersome and less efficient than navigating a single relationship and using a single filter.

The thing to keep in mind is that you need to apply the relationship manipulation step before, not with the filter manipulation step. This looks like the following nested CALCULATE():

```
TotalAmount:=
CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Transactions[Amount])
        ,USERELATIONSHIP(Transactions[MaxDateKey], DimDate[DateKey])
    )
    ,FILTER(
        ALL('Date')
        ,'Date'[Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date])
    )
)
```

Comment: yeah i think this is what we're going to have to go for.. i shall try to have a play with this tomorrow.